# No. of question views in Android app

Tags: feature-request, questions, views, android-app

There should be an indication about **Total Question views**, it should be either under Question title or votes.

One more thing, it would be looking good if question views can be accommodated inside every question row in questions list screen.

Comment: I agree. I don’t use the apps specifically because I like seeing the view count on my questions go up!