# Show the number of question views in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, questions, ios-app, views

This is basically the same as [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193449/no-of-question-views-in-android-app) for the Android app, except I am making the request for the iOS app.

When viewing a question in the iOS app, I'd like to see the total number of views for the question.

Comment: The downvoter should go downvote the Android version of this request too, just to be consistent!

Comment: I think he did.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I can see vote counts, and the Android request has 5 upvotes and 0 downvotes.

Comment: Then maybe he is not using iOS app. Anyway I upvoted.

Comment: Where would you put it?

Comment: @BrianNickel One possibility: When you press on "More" (which is in the same bar as "Favorite", "Edit", and "Share") and get the popup with "Flag", "Close", and "Safari", perhaps add another item in the popup that shows "Viewed N times".

Comment: @BrianNickel Another possibility: Add another bar under the one showing the author avatar/username/badges and latest editor.  In that bar, display a few things like "Viewed N times" and "Asked X days ago".